# The Damworld model of Hamilton and Henderson

Tags: mathematical-modeling, reference-request

I've been reading some of the literature around Lovelock and Watson's famous Daisyworld earth-system model. It is a simple non-linear system of ODEs that illustrates various interesting principles in control theory and ecology/biology.  In quite a few places I find references to another interesting-sounding model formulated by William Hamilton and Peter Henderson: *Damworld.*

> Imagine Damworld as a basin ringed by
>   mountains, in which a single species
>   of algae lives. The rain that falls
>   into Damworld can leave only through
>   one narrow outlet. Living in the
>   outlet are creatures that feed on the
>   algae. These creatures anchor
>   themselves to the sediments and tend
>   to build up a dam, like coral polyps 
>   build up a reef. The third species is
>   one that breaks down dams for food. If
>   the dam rises, the lake behind it
>   swells, creating a larger supply of
>   sunlight-warmed,  nutrient-rich water
>   in which various organisms thrive.

(From Oliver Morton's 1999 article, "Is the Earth Alive?")

**Question:**  Are there any published accounts of the Damworld model?

I've been unable to find anything beyond simple descriptions of Damworld, such as the one above.

(Note: I'm perfectly capable of coding my own version of Damworld - but I'd like to read about the original one.)